# Detecting misusage of delete[] vs. delete at compile time

Tags: c++, compiler, error-detection

I'd like to know if it's possible to detect the `delete` error commented below at compile time? Especially, I'd like to hear about g++ compiler.

```cpp
ClassTypeA *abc_ptr = new ClassTypeA[100];  
abc_ptr[10].data_ = 1;  
delete abc_ptr; // error, should be delete []
```

Comment: You should not be calling delete manually anyway.

Comment: @LokiAstari Did you actually think that comment was helpful?

Comment: @James: Yes. The key is "manually".

Comment: Sometimes to comply with this would involve rewriting a lot of legacy code

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr<ClassTypeA[]>` and then you don't need to.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question asked, but you can detect on Clang at runtime with [AddressSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html). It's like valgrind, but slowdown is only 2x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the compiler can't detect such errors. Example: Suppose the constructor for some class allocates some data member using `new TypeName[]`, but the destructor erroneously uses `delete` instead of `delete[]`. If the constructor and destructor are defined in separate compilation units, how is the compiler to know when compiling the file that defines the destructor that the usage is inconsistent with that in the separately compiled file that defines the constructor?

With regard to the GNU compilers, it doesn't. As noted above, it can't do so in the general case. A compiler doesn't have to detect such mismatched new/delete errors because this is undefined behavior. UB is the compiler vendor's "get out of jail free" card.

Tools such as valgrind can and do detect these kinds of new/delete mismatches, but do so at runtime. There might be a static analysis tool that looks at all of the source files that will eventually be compiled to form an executable, but I don't of any such static analysis tool that detect this kind of error.

Comment: I've used a static analysis tool called [Parasoft](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/home.jsp) that definitely has a rule for this specific scenario. It does run on all of the files in a particular project (if it's been configured correctly). That being said, I'm not certain how well it handles scenarios such as Pete Kirkham's comment on Kilian Foth's answer.

Answer (score 27):

You can use the appropriate RAII classes to `delete`. This is the only safe way of doing it, and this error is only one of the very, very many you will encounter calling `delete` yourself.

Always use classes to manage dynamic lifetime resources, and the type system will enforce correct resource destruction.

Edit: "What if you're auditing the code and can't change it?" You're fucked.

Comment: -1 because this *does not actually answer the question.*

Comment: The only way to detect the mismatch is to use the type system, which involves using RAII classes.

Comment: ...that makes even less sense.  What does the use of RAII classes--a runtime mechanism--have to do with static type system information that the compiler knows about at compile-time?

Comment: @MasonWheeler see boost::shared_ptr and boost::shared_array as examples. Destroying the shared_ptr deletes the object, destroying the shared_array delete[]s the array. You can't assign a shared_array to a shared_ptr, so - as long as you don't construct a shared_ptr with an array in the first place - the type system prevents the wrong delete being used.

Comment: Normally, an answer like this is more obnoxious than helpful. However, in this case, it is actually true. He's looking for compiler enforcement of a common error, and using RAII properly prevents this style of error, thereby giving him exactly what he wants. +1

Comment: @MasonWheeler: for backward compatibility with C, C++ allows automatic conversion from T[] to T*.  To get compile-time type safety, one must use C++ encapsulations of C arrays and pointers.  These encapsulations also prevent memory leaks.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Using a separate class for each resource lifts that run-time behaviour into a compile-time behaviour. The compiler automatically calls the correct destructor of the type- so simply create an object of the correct type, and the problem is solved.

Comment: And where is the example?

Comment: What example? Every C++ programmer should know RAII- else, he needs a lot more than just a quick example from me.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: I disagree. This answer the question in the correct way. You use wrappers to do it automatically.

Comment: In no way does this answer the question. How about the case of someone who isn't given the resources/permissiom to modify any code but wants to make sure the existing code is behaving correctly, i.e an audit?

Comment: @DeadMG Not really, there are static analysers that can pick up this sort of thing.

Comment: @James I believe he means "What good is detecting it if you can't change it anyway?" What good is detecting the problem if all you can do is complain that it's there?

Comment: @corsiKa You get to make a case for fixing it. No-one's going to pay to fix something that isn't proven to be broken.

Comment: @kevin cline: Even with C-backward compatibility, I never really understood the need for `delete` and `delete []`. By looking at the amount of memory allocated to a pointer, the runtime can determine how much memory should be deallocated (just like the C function `free()` would do). Additionally, by dividing this amount of allocated memory by `sizeof(ClassTypeA)` the runtime should know how many times it has to call the destructor and which address should be used each time. It would be interesting to know why this is not possible and one has to write `delete []` explicitly.

Comment: @DeadMG: I am also down-voting this answer because (1) saying that one should use RAII is a very good piece of advice, but should be at most a side comment to this answer, (2) the real question "why the compiler cannot detect the error statically" is reasonable and has not been addressed at all.

Comment: @Giorgio: Because you are assuming that all of the memory is filled with an object. This is not necessarily true at all- for example, memory allocator padding, to say the least.

Comment: @Giorgio: Secondly, he does not ask *why* the compiler cannot detect it, he asks *if* it can detect it. Since I stated that RAII is the only safe way to go, that would imply that the compiler cannot solve this problem for you.

Comment: @James: Technically, the static analyzers can find trivial cases, but writing tests and using static analyzers can never, ever, show that this bug did not occur. Only using the type system can prove that this bug does not exist. The only thing using an analyzer can prove is that you caught all the cases the analyzer could figure out. It does not at all imply that the bug does not exist.

Comment: @DeadMG: But the runtime should know what the memory allocator does. Otherwise how can `delete []` work?

Comment: "he does not ask why the compiler cannot detect it, he asks if it can detect it": fair enough, but adding at least one short sentence saying that it is not possible would improve the answer IMO. Also, my point is why the compiler cannot generate code to look at the amount of memory that is being deallocated and infer that it is deallocating an array. There should be no need for the double syntax `delete`, `delete []`. But you are right that this is a topic for another question.

Comment: @Giorgio: But the size of memory allocated and the size of memory used for objects is *not the same*. The memory allocator overhead doesn't have an object in it, and destructing an object which was not constructed is the bad. The memory allocator cannot know how much memory was used for objects. The other side of this coin is that `delete` should not even exist, let alone `delete[]`, and it's certainly true that nobody should ever, ever, call `delete[]` from their programs.

Comment: If you're auditing the code then take your own copy, change it to RAII, and see what breaks. Company policy usually relates to committing the changes, not making them.

Comment: anyone who thinks "all C++ programmers know about RAII" is living in a dream world.

Comment: I don't think they all do. I do however think that it's mandatory to qualify as a vaguely competent C++ programmer and it's the only way to achieve remote sanity where resource management is involved in C++.

Answer (score 10):

This particular error - yes. This *kind* of error generally: unfortunately, no! That would involve predicting the flow of execution without actually executing it, and that isn't possible for arbitrary programs. (That's why most compilers don't even try to detect simple cases like your example.)

Therefore DeadMG's answer is the appropriate one: don't try to get it right by paying attention - human attention is fallible. Use the language-provided means and let the computer pay attention.

Comment: How does this require predicting the flow of execution? This looks like purely static, compile-time knowledge to me; the compiler's type system knows what's an array and what isn't.

Comment: Even in the presence of casts? Sorry, if I got that wrong I'll delete the answer.

Comment: @MasonWheeler the static type of abc_ptr is `ClassTypeA*` so you can insert a line between the new and the delete `if ( rand() % 2 == 1 ) abc_ptr = new ClassTypeA;` Nothing in the static type system is showing whether `abc_ptr` points to an array or a dynamic object or part way into another object or array.

Comment: ...oh, right.  I'm so used to working with languages with real array types that I keep forgetting how screwed up it is over in C-land. :(

Comment: @Pete Kirkham, @Mason Wheeler: But still, the runtime should see how many objects are stored at the address pointed to by `abc_ptr`, otherwise how could it be able to deallocate the right amount of memory? So the runtime knows how many objects must be deallocated.

Comment: @Giorgio there is nothing in the C++ standard which requires that behaviour. For example , the runtime might implement new and delete in terms of malloc and free, and rely on them to know about the size of the object. If new[] allocates an extra word to hold number of elements in the array, and new does not, then delete won't check the array bounds, and calling delete[] on a object created by new will read from unallocated memory. You're sort-of right in that runtimes which make that optimisation are brittle and most don't do that, but you cannot rely on a particular runtime's strategy.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham: I am not saying that it is required by the C++ standard. But the information is there: the compiler knows how much memory is allocated to each object (it must be known otherwise the compiler cannot compute the offsets of the objects in order to call the destructors correctly), and at runtime the total size of the block being deallocated is also known. From this you can derive the number of objects. So, all the needed information must be there but for some reason this weird distinction between `delete` and `delete []` was introduced.

Comment: @Giorgio I just gave a counter example of how a C++ runtime might be in within the spec but not have the information. You could create a non-C++ language without the distinction, but C++ gives the runtime the option of making single objects one word smaller if they want to.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham: I cannot swear that my argument is correct, but my argument was that you do not need that extra word in either case (because an extra space allocated to hold the length of the allocated are must be allocated anyway by the memory / heap management routine) so adding this extra word would be superfluous anyway. Or do you mean that the intention was to leave the flexibility to implement an own memory manager that does not use the library functions `free()` and `malloc()`?

Comment: @Giorgio not all memory allocators do record the size - for example, you can use different arenas for each power of 2 size, you know by the pointer's address which arena it belongs, and so how to free it. Useful if you want to create lots of objects of only a few bytes size without wasting half your memory on headers.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham: do you have a link to some resource where I can read how this works?

Comment: @Giorgio it's quite a while since I was doing work with it, so I can't find any papers right now - you could always ask your own question on 'header-less' or 'zero overhead' memory allocation.

Answer (score 4):

The trivial case which you show can be detected at compile time, because the instantiation and destruction of the object are in the same scope. In general, the deletion is no in the same scope, or even the same source file, as the instantiation. 
And a C++ pointer's type does not carry information about whether it references a single object of its type or an array, let alone the allocation scheme. So it is not possible to diagnose this at compile time in general.

Why not diagnose the special cases that are possible?

In C++ there are already tools for dealing with leakage of dynamic resources that are tied to scopes, namely smart pointers and higher level arrays (`std::vector`).

Even if you use the correct `delete` flavor, your code is still not exception safe. If the code between the `new[]` and `delete[]` terminates by a dynamic exit, the deletion never executes.

As far as run-time detection goes, the `Valgrind` tool does a good job of detecting this at run-time. Watch:

```
==26781== Command: ./a.out
==26781==
==26781== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==26781==    at 0x402ACFC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==26781==    by 0x8048498: main (in /home/kaz/test/a.out)
==26781==  Address 0x4324028 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 80 alloc'd
==26781==    at 0x402B454: operator new[](unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==26781==    by 0x8048488: main (in /home/kaz/test/a.out)
```

Of course, Valgrind doesn't run on all platforms, and it's not always practical or possible to reproduce all run-time situations under the tool.

Comment: you say that this trivial case can be detected at compile time. Could you please tell me what compilation command you use to achieve that?

Comment: "can be detected at compile time" here means that it is easy to implement in a compiler, not that g++ has it. A compiler has the whole lifetime of the identifier in its grasp when processing that scope, and can propagate the allocation info as as semantic attribute tied to the syntax.

Answer (score -2):

### Some trivial examples of detection at compile-time / static-analysis-time:

#### On a RHEL7 host with `cppcheck 1.77 and 1.49`

```
> cat test.cc
#include <memory>
int main(){char* buf = new char[10];delete buf;}
```

http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/

```
> cppcheck -x c++ test.cc
Checking test.cc ...
[test.cc:2]: (error) Mismatching allocation and deallocation: buf
```

#### With `clang++ 3.7.1` on RHEL7

```
> clang++ --analyze -x c++ test.cc
test.cc:2:37: warning: Memory allocated by 'new[]' should be deallocated by
'delete[]', not 'delete'
int main(){char* buf = new char[10];delete buf;}
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

The Clang Static Analyzer can also detect when `std::unique_ptr` is not passed `<char[]>`

```
> cat test2.cc
#include <memory>
int main(){std::unique_ptr<char> buf(new char[10]);}
```

https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/

```
> clang++ --analyze -x c++ -std=c++11 test2.cc
In file included from test2.cc:1:
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/
../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/memory:81:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/
../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/unique_ptr.h:76:2: 
warning: Memory allocated by
      'new[]' should be deallocated by 'delete[]', not 'delete'
        delete __ptr;
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Update below with a link to the work that added this to clang, the tests and one bug I found.

This was added to clang with reviews.llvm.org/D4661 - *"Detect mismatching 'new' and 'delete' uses"*.

Tests are in test/Analysis/MismatchedDeallocator-checker-test.mm

I found this open bug - bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24819

Comment: No-one doubts that you can find a static analyser that detects *one specific* wrong usage, instead one that detects *all* wrong usages (and hopefully mistakes *no right* usages)